# Classifying spaces beyond CW complexes

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

We know that for a reasonable topological group $G$ (say a compact Lie group) admits a classifying space for $G$-bundles within the category of countable CW complexes. That means, there is a space $BG$ such that homotopy classes of maps from a CW complex $X$ to $BG$ classifies $G$-bundles over $X$ up to isomorphism.

I would like to know if there is any **reference** for cases where the spaces are worse than CW complexes, for example, for compact Hausdorff spaces. In practice one may need to work with certain pathological spaces such as various moduli spaces of solutions to some elliptic PDE (like pseudoholomorphic curves).

Comment: This nlab page (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/classifying+space )  cites Rudolf-Schmidt (Thm. 3.5.1 of: Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics Part II. Fibre Bundles, Topology and Gauge Fields, Springer 2017) and says that Milnor's version of BG works for any X which is a paracompact Hausdorff space.

Comment: The assumption of paracompact Hausdorff can be dropped if one is willing to classify only **numerable** G-bundles over arbitrary spaces. On paracompact Hausdorff spaces every locally trivial bundle is numerable.

Comment: This is because the universal bundles over both Milnor's BG is already numerable. The advantage of Milnor's construction over Segal's is that Segal's works when the inclusion of the identity element is a closed cofibration, so a mild topological restriction on G. But I don't believe there is any additional condition needed on X.

Comment: A textbook account of the above can be found in tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology", Chapter 14.4.